# bacterium as a sphere, calculating distance based on max. metabolic activity - question on comprehension

Tags: diffusion

[image]

Exercise 7.1 c) is seen on the picture above. It states that a bacterium has a given metabolic activity. I get, how the activity is divided through the max. metab. activity gives the max. depletion. then, why would you take the root of the squared radius of the bacterium? What exactly does this imply? my notion is, that this gives a one-directional distance. but how is the root2 of R related to this? like, is there a figuartive explanation to it?

is it maybe that the max. metabolic activity given as the outcome of a sphere (volume) and taking the root of just the radius in the second exercise c) does somehow assume that the bacterium is now only seen as a circle or even just uni-directional distance?

Answer (score 0):

R is the radius of the bacterium. The bacterium is still being approximated as a sphere (3D), but the nice thing about spheres is they can be fully specified by only one quantity, the radius. Although R is 1D, it describes a 3D object.